# Set wireless channel on a DD-WRT router via SSH

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, dd-wrt

I'm trying to change the wireless channel on my DD-WRT v24-sp2 router via SSH. I can persist the channel settings by running;

```
$ nvram set wl_channel=X
$ nvram set wl0_channel=X
```

But this doesn't affect the current channel (e.g., I have to restart the router for the changes to take effect). What command applies the wireless settings in nvram?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what this command really does but running it changes the wireless channel.

```
$ rc start
```